# Which data files output format from C++ to be read in python (or other) is more size efficient?

Tags: python, c++, io

I want to write output files containing tabular datas (float values in lines and columns) from a C++ program.
I need to open those files later on with other languages/softwares (here python and paraview, but might change).
What would be the most efficient output format for tabular files (efficient for files memory sizes efficiency) that would be compatible with other languages ?

E.g., txt files, csv, xml, binarized or not ?

Thanks for advices

Comment: You have answered your own question (in the question)

Comment: Sorry @RichardCritten, i don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDF5 might be a good option for you. It’s a standard format for storing large amounts of data, and there are Python and C++ libraries for reading and writing to it.

See [here for an example](https://gmsciprog.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/simple-hdf5-for-python-and-c/)

Answer (score 2):

1- Your output files contain tabular data (float values in lines and columns), in other words, a kind of matrix.

2- You need to open those files later on with other languages/softwares

3- You want to have files memory sizes efficiency

That's said, you have to consider one of the two formats below:

- CSV: if your data are very simple (a matrix of float without particualr structure)
- JSON if you need a minimum structure for your files

These two formats are standard, supported by almost all the known languages and maintained softwares.

Last, if your data have a great complexity structure, prefer to look at a format like XML but the price to pay is then in the size of your files!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of the JSON one, i will have a look at it too !

Answer (score 0):

First of all the efficiency of i/o operations is limited by the buffer size. So if you want to achieve higher throughput you might have to play with the input output buffers. And regarding your doubt of what way to output into the files is dependent on your data and what delimiters you want to use to separate the data in the files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not concerned about the I/O speed efficiency, but only on the final output files size. My datas are numbers (double) and separated in the files by `;` as paraview could not read columns separated by '\t' for some reason.

Comment: if you can store values separated by `,` then you can use pandas or any equivalent csv reader to read those files again. I'd prefer this because most languages have libraries to read and write from csv files